# URL rewrite rule not working on localhost (apache)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my link: `http://localhost/test/index.php`

Now i want to change it to look like this: `http://localhost/home/`

So i create a .htaccess file and placed it inside the **test** folder.

This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test/index.php$ home/
```

**mod_rewrite** is also enabled.

But anyway this rule is not working for me and browser is redirecting me to the original url `http://localhost/test/index.php`. However i tried this rule online and it seemed working there. Here's the snapshot of the website where i tested the rule.

[image]

Comment: Do you can explain your errors?

Comment: What error is browser writing?

Comment: Browser is simply redirecting me to original url: http://localhost/test/index.php

Comment: @AdnanAhmed is your apache.conf file has any 'AllowOverride None' statement?

Comment: @RohitBatra all of them are 'AllowOverride All'

Comment: @AdnanAhmed tried restarting the apache service? check your error-logs for any errors once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have 2 complimentary rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# external redirect for chancing URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+test/index\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ home/ [L,R=302]

# internal routing to actual URL
RewriteRule ^home/?$ test/index.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these paths:

1. In terminal run `a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache.
2. ### Apache upto 2.3

If it was done , Do the following,

go to this directory,

`cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/`

`sudo gedit default`

Replaces this line :

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all`

and change it as below

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all`

Then start apache server

`sudo service apache2 restart`

### Apache 2.4+

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Add following in the end

```

### Removes error that comes up while restarting server

ServerName localhost

### phpmyadmin 404 error resolved

Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Also set `AllowOverride All` for `/var/www` Directory

Then follow these steps

`sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www`

Restart `apache`

Done!!!

#### Check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` if still facing problems